# How to pause a mobile robot during navigation?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

How to pause a mobile robot during navigation?
How to make the robot restore after the pause?

In my application, I expect the robot can pause for some while after I set the navigation goal. And restore into the navigation process after the pause.

I am now using turtlebot with ROS navigation stack.

Best Regards,
Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223263/how-to-pause-a-mobile-robot-during-navigation?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, this is not currently not possible with the navigation stack.

What do you mean by "pause"? Just standing still?

If yes, there are several ways how to do this.
IMHO, the prefered one would probably be do implement a service in the base controller which let's you de/activate reacting to any velocity commands from the navigation stack.

If you need to drive around, you could use the [`twist_mux`](http://wiki.ros.org/twist_mux) node and have something with higher priority then the navigation but lower then what else you need, which is sending zeros.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajmohan747](https://answers.ros.org/users/35106/rajmohan747/) on 2020-12-14**:
@mgruhler:  As far as I understand, even if command velocities are being pulled down with twist_mux, the local planner will still keep on replanning. And eventually, this will lead to a series of recovery behaviors, on exhausting of which, the goal will be getting failed.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-12-14**:
You might be right. Though I'm not entirely sure what triggers the recovery behaviors. I thought this would be triggered if the local planner doesn't find a valid path due to obstacles. But other things might factor into this as well.